# Кортеж в Python. Сложение элементов разных типов

Tags: python, итераторы, tuple

Задача следующая.
Разработать функцию, принимающую любое количество аргументов и возвращает их сумму.

Проверки следующие:

```
assert big_summa(1, 2, 3) == 6
assert big_summa(i for i in range(10)) == 45
assert big_summa((i for i in range(10)), 1) == 46
assert big_summa(2, (i for i in range(10)), 1) == 48
assert big_summa({-1, 1, 0}) == 0
```

Моё решение этой задачи:

```
import itertools


def big_summa(*args):
    sum_item = 0
    for item in args:
        if isinstance(item, int):
            sum_item = list(itertools.accumulate(args))[-1]

        else:
            for elem in item:
                sum_item += elem
    return sum_item
```

Я воспользовался методом accumulate(), который возвращает в форме списка сумму с нарастающим итогом и взял оттуда последний элемент. Такой код проходит только для первого assert(a) c простыми числами.
Далее, c блоком else проходят еще второй и пятый assert.

На кортеж состоящий из range() и простых чисел выпадает исключение:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\level02.py", line 24, in <module>
    assert big_summa((i for i in range(10)), 1) == 46
  File ".\level02.py", line 8, in big_summa
    sum_item = list(itertools.accumulate(args))[-1]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'generator' and 'int'
```

Исключение говорит о том, что сложить генератор и число нельзя.
Не могу разобраться как надо разобрать на составляющие генератор и сложить их с остальными элементами кортежа.

Как новичок, хотел бы попутно узнать какими библиотеками можно руководствоваться при таком типе задач.

Comment: Что-то не пойму, зачем так сложно. Разве блок в else не делает всё, что нужно, со списками/генераторами? В if надо просто добавить к сумме текущий item. А тут получается вы увидели, что первый элемент - число, и дальше что-то делаете с остальными аргументами, не глядя на их тип.

Comment: Как в блоке if  добавить существующий item?
Да, если в списке одни числа, для них и приведено готовое решение. Если типы разные то подразумевался блок else. 
Такая была идея, но не получается))

Comment: `list(itertools.accumulate(args))[-1]` ≈ `sum(args)` только еще и с пустыми последовательностями работает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Однострочник ))

```
def big_summa(*args):
    return sum(big_summa(*a) if hasattr(a, '__iter__') else a for a in args)
```

По идее оно должно работать даже при любом уровне вложенности

Comment: что значит часть  if hasattr(a, '__iter__')?)

Comment: @Stanlyzoolo, это проверка на то, является ли __a__ итерируемым объектом.

Comment: еще поясните про big_summa(*a)  в строке return)
Спасибо)

Comment: @Stanlyzoolo, это рекурсивный вызов - то есть функция вызывает сама себя но уже не для всех входных аргументов, а для внутренних элементов только одного из аргументов.

Comment: спасибо за интересный ответ, он мне очень помог на курсах!))

Answer (score 4):

Я решил таким способом:

```
def big_summa(*args):
    sum_item = sum(i if type(i) in (int, float) else sum(i) for i in args)
    return sum_item
```

Т.е. мы создаем генератор, в котором если аргумент не Int или float, то мы считаем его итерируемым и считаем его сумму. А потом считаем сумму всех элементов генератора. Можно сделать дополнительную проверку `hasattr(i, '__iter__')`
, чтобы убедиться, что это итератор.

Comment: `return sum(i if type(i) in (int, float) else sum(i) for i in args)` ?

Comment: Часть `if type(i) in (int, float)` какую функцию несет?

Comment: @Alpensin
Поясните, пожалуйста.
Часть `if type(i) in (int, float)` какую функцию несет?
Мы проводим проверку `item` на тип, если `True` выполняется `sum`. 
Если не `True` выполнение переходит к блоку `else`, где суммируется распакованные `range()`?)

Comment: Да, верно. Хотя наверно правильней как предлагает Xander, где мы проверяем является ли аргумент итерируемым, и если да -  суммируем его элементы.